# z-index stacking context with two overlaid areas

Tags: html, css, z-index

Here is my code

**HTML**

```
<div class="left">
   <div class="rectangle"></div>
</div>
<div class="right">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 30%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  z-index: 10;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 30%;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  z-index: 20;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.rectangle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

left area has z-index less than z-index of the right area, but z-index of rectangle greater than both of the areas but it's invisible.

Question: is it possible to make rectangle visible without changing z-index attributes of both areas?

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pshenichnov/o3n2Lwyf/)

Comment: Not possible without change z-index or html

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/lnb596844/o3n2Lwyf/1/

Comment: @e-designary, not that's not what I'm looking for... I don't want to change rectangle's position as well.

Comment: @DaniP, that's what I was thinking about... :(

Comment: What is the goal?

Comment: What about removing `z-index` from `.left` and `.right`?